# WordNet with swi-prolog

Tags: macos, swi-prolog, wordnet

I'm trying to use the WordNet package for swi-prolog and I can't seem to be able to use it after install. I'm on MacOS Big Sur. I have tried fresh installs with both homebrew and macports, and I've even tried the docker container and I get the same error every time.

This is the process and ouput:

```
derek@Dereks-MBP-2 thelazyreader % swipl
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.2.4)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit https://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- pack_install(wordnet).
% Contacting server at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/query ... ok
Select download location for wordnet@0.9.3
   (1) * https://api.github.com/repos/JanWielemaker/wordnet/zipball/V0.9.3
   (2)   GIT repository at https://github.com/JanWielemaker/wordnet.git
   (3)   Cancel

Your choice? 
% Contacting server at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/query ... ok
% "V0.9.3" was downloaded 46 times
Package:                wordnet
Title:                  Access to WordNet database
Installed version:      0.9.3
Author:                 Jan Wielemaker <jan@swi-prolog.org>
Home page:              https://github.com/JanWielemaker/wordnet
Download URL:           https://github.com/JanWielemaker/wordnet/releases/*.zip
Install "wordnet-0.9.3" (7,451 bytes) Y/n? 
true.

?- pack_list_installed.
Installed packages (1):

i wordnet@0.9.3             - Access to WordNet database
true.

?- use_module(library(wordnet)).
ERROR: source_sink `library(wordnet)' does not exist
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [19] throw(error(existence_error(source_sink,...),_12810))
ERROR:   [15] '$resolve_source_path'(library(wordnet),_12842,[if(not_loaded),...]) at /opt/local/lib/swipl/boot/init.pl:2318
ERROR:   [14] '$load_file'(library(wordnet),user,[if(not_loaded),...]) at /opt/local/lib/swipl/boot/init.pl:2292
ERROR:    [9] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
?-
```

If I run in debug mode this is the output I get...

```
[debug]  ?- use_module(library(wordnet)).
ERROR: source_sink `library(wordnet)' does not exist
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [19] throw(error(existence_error(source_sink,...),_4386))
ERROR:   [18] '$existence_error'(source_sink,library(wordnet)) at /opt/local/lib/swipl/boot/init.pl:3794
ERROR:   [17] '$abs_file_error'(library(wordnet),[],[file_type(prolog),...]) at /opt/local/lib/swipl/boot/init.pl:1221
ERROR:   [16] absolute_file_name(library(wordnet),_4496,[file_type(prolog),...]) at /opt/local/lib/swipl/boot/init.pl:1157
ERROR:   [15] '$resolve_source_path'(library(wordnet),_4544,[if(not_loaded),...]) at /opt/local/lib/swipl/boot/init.pl:2318
ERROR:   [14] '$load_file'(library(wordnet),user,[if(not_loaded),...]) at /opt/local/lib/swipl/boot/init.pl:2292
ERROR:   [13] '$load_one_file'(library(wordnet),user,[if(not_loaded),...]) at /opt/local/lib/swipl/boot/init.pl:2128
ERROR:   [12] '$load_files'(library(wordnet),user,[if(not_loaded),...]) at /opt/local/lib/swipl/boot/init.pl:2105
ERROR:   [11] load_files(user:library(wordnet),[if(not_loaded),...]) at /opt/local/lib/swipl/boot/init.pl:2085
ERROR:   [10] use_module(user:library(wordnet)) at /opt/local/lib/swipl/boot/init.pl:2023
ERROR:    [9] <user>
```

I'm stumped here. Any direction on where I can look or what I can try would be most welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Pack page: [Package "wordnet"](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=wordnet)
- Explainer on Wikipedia: [WordNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet)

The module is in a file called `wn.pl`, not `wordnet.pl`.

On my machine, after having run `pack_install(wordnet).`, one finds this:

```
$HOME/.local/share/swi-prolog/pack/wordnet
|
├── pack.pl
├── prolog
│   ├── wn.pl
│   └── wn_portray.pl
└── README.md
```

So:

```
?- use_module(library(wn)).
```

However:

```
ERROR: Cannot find WordNet data files.  Please set the environment
ERROR: variable WNDB to point at the directory holding the WordNet files
```

So these files need to be installed, too.

Comment: This is perfect. Coming from python and js I assumed that the library name would be the same as the install. It never occurred to me to load the specific filename. FYI I put the wordnet files in a directory of my project root and I set the environment variable with `setenv('WNDB', 'wordnet').` and everything is working. Thanks!